# How to connect your household address to its members in civicrm api v3?

Tags: api, addresses, households

```
$result = civicrm_api3('Address', 'create', array(
  'sequential' => 1,
  'contact_id' => $householdContact['id'],
  'location_type_id' => "Home",
  'is_primary' => 1,
  'street_address' => $form_state['storage']['contactInfoValues']['address1'],
  'supplemental_address_1' => $form_state['storage']['contactInfoValues']['address2'],
  'city' => $form_state['storage']['contactInfoValues']['city'],
  'state_province_id' =>  $form_state['storage']['contactInfoValues']['state'],
  'country_id' => "US",
));

$master_address_id = $result['id'];



 $result = civicrm_api3('Address', 'create', array(
          'sequential' => 1,
          'contact_id' => $primaryContact['id'],
          'master_id'  => $master_address_id,
          'location_type_id' => "Home",
        ));
```

I need to attach the household address with primary contact address . How can i achieve I tried by implementing above ,but it did not work?

Answer (score 3):

You need to provide same set of values to create address for members of the household with additional parameter master_id as Address foreign key id of household contact.

```
$addressParams = [
  'sequential' => 1,
  'contact_id' => $householdContact['id'],
  'location_type_id' => "Home",
  'is_primary' => 1,
  'street_address' => $form_state['storage']['contactInfoValues']['address1'],
  'supplemental_address_1' => $form_state['storage']['contactInfoValues']['address2'],
  'city' => $form_state['storage']['contactInfoValues']['city'],
  'state_province_id' =>  $form_state['storage']['contactInfoValues']['state'],
  'country_id' => "US",
];
$result = civicrm_api3('Address', 'create', $addressParams);

$addressParams['master_id'] = $result['id'];
$addressParams['contact_id'] = $primaryContact['id'];
$result = civicrm_api3('Address', 'create', $addressParams);
```

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: Hi @pradeep, I just noticed that, we need to have 'is_primary' & 'location_type_id' to link household address to primary contact or any other 2 contacts which needs to be linked, I found this here in the answer given below and link is https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/865168d5d056d071d23d0273189051241c5261e5/tests/phpunit/CRM/Core/BAO/AddressTest.php#L446 .Also I tried just with master_id and contact_id and it did not work but with is_primary & location_type_id added along with contact_id and master_id it worked!

Answer (score 1):

You are currently supposed to add the address details to the address that is sharing the data from another address.

You can see an example here:
https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/865168d5d056d071d23d0273189051241c5261e5/tests/phpunit/CRM/Core/BAO/AddressTest.php#L446

Your version should already create a linked address, but does not copy over the data.

It seems only import and API suffer from this issue. The GUI actually does copy over the values. This seems like a usefull feature request.